# Best way to override default css in SharePoinrt 2010

Tags: css, sharepoint-2010

I would like all my custom webpart and default webparts to look the same.
And i know css classes likeL:
ms-vh and ms-vb are used for the fonts,anchors and cell bacgrounds.
What would be the best way to override this to have my webparts have one look.
And also would like to have one font for everything.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your own css file to your site template and define styles there.

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430141.aspx) might help you if you are interested in SharePoint branding.